# Issue with alignment of section header in resume

Tags: horizontal-alignment

[image]

```
%-------------------------
% Resume in Latex
% Author : Amlaan Bhoi
% Adapted from: Sourabh Bajaj
% License : MIT
%------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % Bitstream Charter
% \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.50in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.50in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-6pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeItemNoBullet}[2]{
  \item[]\small{
    \hspace{-9pt}\textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-6pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
  \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \hspace{-10pt}\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

% custom commands
\newcommand{\shorterSection}[1]{\vspace{-10pt}\section{#1}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  \small \textbf{\href{abhoi.github.io}{\huge Russ Haight}} \\  \href{haightru@grinnell.edu}{\color{blue}\underline{haightru@grinnell.edu}} $\vert$
  315-400-5536 $\vert$\\
  
  
\end{center}
    
  %-------Actuarial Progress--------%
\shorterSection{Actuarial Exams}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
\begin{itemize}
    \item
    {Exam P} 
    \hfill Pass (March 2019)
    \item
    {Exam FM}
    \hfill Pass (October 2019)
    \item
    {Exam IFM}
    \hfill Pass (July 2020)
    \item{Exam STAM}
    \hfill Pass (February 2021)
    \item
    {All VEE requirements}
    \hfill March 2021
    \item
    {EXAM SRM}
    \hfill Pass (May 2021)
    \item
    {Exam PA}
    \hfill Sitting December 2021
    \end{itemize} 
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
%-----------Education--------%


%-----------Other Analytical EXPERIENCE-----------------
\shorterSection{Actuarial Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
  
  \resumeSubheading
      {Transamerica}{Cedar Rapids, IA}
      {Actuarial Analyst Level 6}{Jan 2020-Present}
      \begin{itemize}
         
         \item Execute KC2A controls to ensure proper transfer of data from admin system to MG-ALFA inforce, and KC2B controls to ensure proper transfer of data from MG-ALFA inforce to MG-ALFA output
         \item Recreate and document the wmA admin transformation process, starting with the raw admin extract and ending with the final inforce file
         \item Utilize Model Manager UI to run the Purchased Annuities Cash Flow Testing model in MG-ALFA
         \item Calculate coverage ratios for the Purchased Annuities block and sample test bed, and create test bed documentation
         \item Correspond with model owners, model developers, and the model change management team to create findings needed for each elevation from development to integration
         \item Navigate ALFA model, inforce files, and output files to provide detailed screenshots to meet the expectations of internal controls and external consultants
          \item Adjust key controls based on ongoing feedback from internal controls and actuarial model development team
          
         
      \end{itemize}
  
  

   \resumeSubheading
      {Global Atlantic Financial group}{Des Moines, IA}
      {Contract Actuarial Analyst }{June 2019 - January 2020}
      \begin{itemize}
          \item Calculate Cash Surrender Value, Death Benefit, and Cost Basis for American Mutual Life Whole Life and Universal Life policies
          \item Adjust prorated premium calculations for contract changes and remittances not in system
          \item Communicate with various internal and external personnel regarding information necessary for calculations
          \item Research and analyze life insurance policies to improve integrity and accuracy of customer policy data
          \item Respond to requests regarding changes in policy values and annual statements in a timely and accurate manner
          \item Incorporate manual transactions into updated loan and illustration tools accordingly
      \end{itemize}
      
\shorterSection{Additional Experience}
      \resumeSubheading
      {Huntington Learning Center}{Fayetteville, NY}
      {SAT and Subject Tutor}{September 2018 - June 2019}
      

    \resumeSubheading
      {Grinnell College Math Department}{Grinnell, IA}
      {Student Researcher}{May 2017-August 2017}
      
    
         

    \resumeSubheading
      {Grinnell College Math Department}{Grinnell, IA}
      {Grader}{January 2017 - May 2018}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! And what is the issue please? Can you show a screenshot ?

Comment: one section of my resume does not align with the others

Comment: Specifically the "additional expereince section".  I have posted that block of code and the resume

Comment: Please add the code before this section too, perhaps the space comes from that code ....

Comment: Posted the code but still needs to be reformatted-Im not sure how to designate things sucessfully as code

Comment: Added a screenshot of the issue

Answer (score 1):

Before and after your text "Additional Experience" is a code line missing. Added code see here:

```
\resumeSubHeadingListEnd% <========================================= missing

\shorterSection{Additional Experience}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart% <========================================= missing
```

With the following complete code

```
%------------------------- % Resume in Latex % Author : Amlaan Bhoi % Adapted from: Sourabh Bajaj % License : MIT %------------------------

\documentclass[letterpaper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex, hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign} % Bitstream Charter
% \usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % Palatino

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.50in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.50in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.5in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1.0in}

\urlstyle{same}

\raggedbottom
\raggedright
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}

% Sections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-6pt}\scshape\raggedright\large
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]

%-------------------------
% Custom commands
\newcommand{\resumeItem}[2]{
  \item\small{
    \textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-2pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeItemNoBullet}[2]{
  \item[]\small{
    \hspace{-9pt}\textbf{#1}{: #2 \vspace{-6pt}}
  }
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubheading}[4]{
  \vspace{-1pt}\item[]
  \begin{tabular*}{0.98\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \hspace{-10pt}\textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \hspace{-10pt}\textit{\small#3} & \textit{\small #4} \\
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
}

\newcommand{\resumeSubItem}[2]{\resumeItem{#1}{#2}\vspace{-4pt}}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}

\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListStart}{\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*]}
\newcommand{\resumeSubHeadingListEnd}{\end{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListStart}{\begin{itemize}}
\newcommand{\resumeItemListEnd}{\end{itemize}\vspace{-5pt}}

% custom commands
\newcommand{\shorterSection}[1]{\vspace{-10pt}\section{#1}}

%-------------------------------------------
%%%%%%  CV STARTS HERE  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}


\begin{center}
  \small \textbf{\href{abhoi.github.io}{\huge Russ Haight}} \\  \href{haightru@grinnell.edu}{\color{blue}\underline{haightru@grinnell.edu}} $\vert$
  315-400-5536 $\vert$\\
  
  
\end{center}
    
  %-------Actuarial Progress--------%
\shorterSection{Actuarial Exams}
\resumeSubHeadingListStart
%\begin{itemize}
    \item {Exam P}    \hfill Pass (March 2019)
    \item {Exam FM}    \hfill Pass (October 2019)
    \item {Exam IFM}    \hfill Pass (July 2020)
    \item {Exam STAM}    \hfill Pass (February 2021)
    \item {All VEE requirements}    \hfill March 2021
    \item {EXAM SRM}   \hfill Pass (May 2021)
    \item {Exam PA}    \hfill Sitting December 2021
%   \end{itemize} 
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd
%-----------Education--------%


%-----------Other Analytical EXPERIENCE-----------------
\shorterSection{Actuarial Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart
  
  \resumeSubheading
      {Transamerica}{Cedar Rapids, IA}
      {Actuarial Analyst Level 6}{Jan 2020-Present}
      \begin{itemize}
         \item Execute KC2A controls to ensure proper transfer of data from admin system to MG-ALFA inforce, and KC2B controls to ensure proper transfer of data from MG-ALFA inforce to MG-ALFA output
         \item Recreate and document the wmA admin transformation process, starting with the raw admin extract and ending with the final inforce file
         \item Utilize Model Manager UI to run the Purchased Annuities Cash Flow Testing model in MG-ALFA
         \item Calculate coverage ratios for the Purchased Annuities block and sample test bed, and create test bed documentation
         \item Correspond with model owners, model developers, and the model change management team to create findings needed for each elevation from development to integration
         \item Navigate ALFA model, inforce files, and output files to provide detailed screenshots to meet the expectations of internal controls and external consultants
          \item Adjust key controls based on ongoing feedback from internal controls and actuarial model development team
      \end{itemize}

   \resumeSubheading
      {Global Atlantic Financial group}{Des Moines, IA}
      {Contract Actuarial Analyst }{June 2019 - January 2020}
      \begin{itemize}
          \item Calculate Cash Surrender Value, Death Benefit, and Cost Basis for American Mutual Life Whole Life and Universal Life policies
          \item Adjust prorated premium calculations for contract changes and remittances not in system
          \item Communicate with various internal and external personnel regarding information necessary for calculations
          \item Research and analyze life insurance policies to improve integrity and accuracy of customer policy data
          \item Respond to requests regarding changes in policy values and annual statements in a timely and accurate manner
          \item Incorporate manual transactions into updated loan and illustration tools accordingly
      \end{itemize}
    \resumeSubHeadingListEnd% <========================================= missing

\shorterSection{Additional Experience}
  \resumeSubHeadingListStart% <========================================= missing
      \resumeSubheading
      {Huntington Learning Center}{Fayetteville, NY}
      {SAT and Subject Tutor}{September 2018 - June 2019}

    \resumeSubheading
      {Grinnell College Math Department}{Grinnell, IA}
      {Student Researcher}{May 2017-August 2017}

    \resumeSubheading
      {Grinnell College Math Department}{Grinnell, IA}
      {Grader}{January 2017 - May 2018}
  \resumeSubHeadingListEnd

\end{document}
```

you get the wished result like

[image: resulting page]